# Silviomoreto bootstrap-select tooltip on options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Silviomoreto bootstrap-select add to select `"display:none"`:

[image]
and it make visible 'ul' like this:

[image]

I change this select dynamically:

```
for(var key in value) {
    $(this)
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", key)
        .text(value[key])); 
}              
$(this).selectpicker('refresh');
```

How can I dynamically add a tooltip to each option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add the tooltip to each generated `li` element, rather than the `option` elements (after `bootstrap-select` is initialized). You can access the generated `li` elements using `data('selectpicker')`.

```
$('#selectID').data('selectpicker').$lis.attr('title', 'New Title').tooltip();
```

Comment: totally worked for me. im using mvc with kendo and was struggling to add a tool tip.

Comment: This is how i dynamically generated my tooltip. Thanks to this Answer :) Var tooltipMap = {};
Tooltip[“text”]=”tooltip”; //these were dynamically generated 
$('#id-dropdown').data('selectpicker').$lis.each(function () {  
    var li = $(this);
    var elementtext = li.find('span.text').text();
    var tooltipString = tooltipMap[elementtext];
    if (tooltipString) {
          li.tooltip({
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'right',
           title: tooltipString
            });
        }
                            
    });

Answer (score 2):

Tooltip does not work dynamically with bs select.

It gives all select item same value "test", but when move the mouse should be changed.

```
$('#id').on('shown.bs.select', function () {
    var test = $('selectpicker').selectpicker.current.elements.text();
    $($(this).data('selectpicker').selectpicker.current.elements).attr('title', test ).tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different way to do it that will pump the tooltip attribute off the options and put them on to the bootstrap rows

```
var tips = [];
$('#selectID option').each(function(){
    tips.push($(this).attr('tooltip'));
});

$('#selectID').data('selectpicker').$lis.each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('title',tips[i]).tooltip() 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got Sovtek's answer working with some modification, this time taking the title attribute defined in the option(s) and setting it to the title of the generated Bootstrap-select
element:

```
var tips = [];
$('#mySelectPickerID option').each(function () {
    tips.push($(this).attr('title'));
});

$('.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu li a span.text').each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('title', tips[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

RBILLC's answer worked for me but for those who doesn't want to use js solution, you can use `data-content` ([ref](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#custom-content)) attribute to insert bootstrap `title` into your element `div`/`span`

For ex:

```
  <select class="selectpicker">
    <option title="Option with tooltip" data-content="<div title='I am your tooltip'><span>Option with tooltip</span><small class='text-muted'>subtext 1...</small></div>"></option>
    <option data-subtext="subtext 1...">Option with tooltip</option>
  </select>
```

**Note**: `data-content` input will be sanitized by bootstrap-select, so in above example, you will need to whitelist `title` attribute on `div` tag ([ref](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#sanitizer))

```
var extendBootstrapSelectSanitizer = $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList;
// To allow div elements and title attributes on td elements
extendBootstrapSelectSanitizer.div = ['title'];
```